# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\senyo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\senyo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:499:15)
    at startMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:436:3)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! argon-react-native@1.3.0 start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the argon-react-native@1.3.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\senyo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-20T07_36_37_359Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you installed all of the dependencies in your `package.json` and used `npm install` ?

Comment: yes i did install them

Comment: Maybe you should modify your `package.json` to run directly from `node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js` unless you want to install expo-cli globally with `npm install -g expo-cli`

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
npm install -g expo-cli --force
```

this works for me

Comment: You saved me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanyou so much @Kushagra Kumar

Answer (score 0):

for me, the node_modules file was missing. check if it is there. To solve the problem I simply went to the control panel->uninstall apps->nodejs(right-click on nodejs)-> select repair. My node_modules file was back.